# Why does SetOptions not know about ImageSize for Show?

Tags: graphics, options, customization

ImageSize works fine as an option for Show when used in a call.

```
Show[image,ImageSize->100]
```

[image]

But SetOptions does not know about that:

```
SetOptions[Show,ImageSize->400]
SetOptions::optnf: ImageSize is not a known option for Show.
```

Does anyone understand this?

V11.0.1 on Win 7 x64

Comment: if you want a workaround, use something like `show[x__] := Show[x, ImageSize -> 400]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a vague memory of this question being asked before but I cannot find it now.

[`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) has no formal options; that is `Options[Show]` is `{}`.  (As MB1965 just posted I see.)  I think this makes sense as `Show` does not really have any options of its own; it instead appends the options it is given to the compound `Graphics` or `Graphics3D` that it creates.  It does not make sense for it to append a large list of default parameters to everything it creates; that would defeat the purpose of the construct IMHO.

Even if we [`Unprotect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unprotect.html) `Show` and give it `Options` it doesn't know what to do with these; they are not applied.  However because of this if we wish we *can* modify the function to make it append our options.

```
Unprotect[Show];

Show[x___] :=
  Block[{$innerShow = True},
    Show[x, Options @ Show]
  ] /; ! TrueQ[$innerShow]

Options[Show] = {ImageSize -> 222};
```

This is a settable option now; i.e. you can use `SetOptions[Show, ImageSize -> 900]` etc.

Now:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];

Show[p1, Background -> LightBlue]

Rasterize[%, "RasterSize"]
```

[image]

> ```
> {222, 125}
> ```

[Jason B.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9490/jason-b)'s recommendation of a user `show` replacement is of course "safer" but what's the fun in that? :^)  You can give it settable Options if you wish:

```
Options[show] = {ImageSize -> 222};

show[x__] := Show[x, Options @ show]
```

Answer (score 5):

Look at `Options`:

```
In[683]:= Options[Show]

Out[683]= {}
```

`SetOptions` only works (at least for what I've seen) when the option is represented in `Options` for the symbol.

`Show` is simply a special beast that combines the graphics objects passed with any options inserted. It does not track the entire set of options any of the graphics it knows about can take.